# Netty message on connect

Tags: netty

I'm just getting started with Netty and wanted to approach it slowly to really understand how things work. I had one initial use case that I wanted to start with, based on a standalone socket test program:

- On connection to the server from the client, send a message immediately and process the response

Easy enough...or so I thought. I've been looking at this for days and not really understanding why this isn't behaving as expected.

Here is the original test program, which again, simply connects to a remote server and immediately writes a bytebuffer to the server. The server then immediately sends an ack response which is just written out to console.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class SocketTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final String host = "remote host";
    final int port = 123456;

    final String msg = "hi";
    final byte sync = (byte)0x02;
    final short value1 = (short)70;
    final byte value2 = (byte)12;
    final byte value3 = (byte)0x4c;
    final int value4 = 1;
    final short value5 = (short)0x03;
    final short value6 = (short)0xffff;

    try {
      SocketChannel socketChannel
          = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

       ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(15);
       buf.put(sync);
       buf.putShort(value1);
       buf.put(value2);
       buf.put(value3);
       buf.putInt(value4);
       buf.putShort(value5);
       buf.putShort(value6);
       buf.put(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
       buf.flip();

       //write
       while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
         socketChannel.write(buf);
       }

       //read
       ByteBuffer inBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(78);
       while (socketChannel.read(inBuf) > 0) {
           System.out.printf("[%s]:\t%s\n", Thread.currentThread().getName(), new String(inBuf.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
       }
    } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
      System.exit(1);
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
      System.exit(1);
    } finally {
      socketChannel.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I took the same test and tried with this basic use case with Netty:

**NettySocketTest**

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;

public class NettySocketTest {

  private final String host;
  private final int port;
  private SocketChannel channelInstance;

  public NettySocketTest(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
  }

  public void start() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
      Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
      b.group(group)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
          @Override
          public void initChannel (SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
            channel.pipeline().addLast(new ClientTestHandler());
          }
        });

      ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync();
      f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
      group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
  }
}
```

**ClientTestHandler**

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class ClientTestHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

  final String msg = "hi";

  @Override
  public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    //existing test code - [1]
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(15);
    buf.put((byte)0x02);
    buf.putShort((short)70);
    buf.put((byte)12);
    buf.put((byte)0x4c);
    buf.putInt(101);
    buf.putShort((short)0x03);
    buf.putShort((short)0xffff);
    buf.put(msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    buf.flip();

    //preferred implementation - [2]
    /**
    CompositeByteBuf messageBuf = Unpooled.compositeBuffer();
    ByteBuf syncBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer(1);
    syncBuf.writeByte((byte)0x02);

    ByteBuf headerBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer(12);
    headerBuf.writeShort((short)70);
    headerBuf.writeByte((byte)12);
    headerBuf.writeByte((byte)0x4c);
    headerBuf.writeInt(101);
    headerBuf.writeShort((short)0x03);
    headerBuf.writeShort((short)0xffff);

    ByteBuf bodyBuf = ctx.alloc().buffer(2);
    bodyBuf.writeBytes("hi".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    messageBuf.addComponents(syncBuf, headerBuf, bodyBuf);
    **/

    //DOESN'T WORK - [3]
    final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(buf);

    //ALSO DOESN'T WORK 
    //final ChannelFuture f = ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(buf);

      f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
          @Override
          public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
              assert f == future;
              ctx.close();
          }
      });
    }

  @Override
  public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object resp) {
    ByteBuf msg = (ByteBuf) resp;
    System.out.println("Response received: " + msg.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }

  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
  }
}
```

In the ClientTestHandler:

1. I took the existing ByteBuffer code and tried to use it as-is before converting to the convenience methods that Netty offers. See #2.
2. This is an attempt at using a CompositeByteBuf. Neither 1 or 2 works.
3. Attempt to write out message using ChannelHandlerContext and another try at using the channel on the context directly, hoping one of the two would illicit a response.

My expectation is for the message to be sent to the server and a response to come and get printed to console.

The client code does:

1. Successfully starts/connects
2. successfully invokes channelActive
3. Successfully invokes operationComplete on the ChannelFutureListener
4. The channelRead0 method is never invoked

I purposefully didn't add anything else to the pipeline so I can start simply and modify the code and learn while I go. I reverted the CompositeByteBuf to the nio.ByteBuffer so i could start with the same code I had in the other test.

Is it correct to use the channelActive to immediately send bytes to the server when connected? Can anyone help me understand what i'm doing wrong with this basic use case and why the response isn't captured (assuming the message is actually sent)?

Comment: What you are doing with `channelActive` is correct only e.g. it's used to send the first message (e.g. handshake, connection established, etc) to server. I am suspecting the server didn't reply anything back to client. Kindly share your server code as well.

Comment: The server is a third party provider and their server code is proprietary. Passing a nio.ByteBuffer into write is correct as depicted? Can’t put my finger on why the non-Netty code gets a response but the same buffer definition within doesn’t...

Comment: can you use netty `ByteBuf` instead?

Comment: Sure. If you check the ClientHandler class I tried using a compositebytebuf to test (which I wasnt able to make work), but never tried just a straight bytebuf. Can give it a shot.

Comment: The ChannelFuture (which I used from sample code) is the problem. Closing the channel prevented the response from the server from being received. Removing the listener, everything behaved as expected!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is caused by the fact that on the moment your handler is added to the pipeline, it is already connected. This is unlike the client, where the client still needs to resolve the server's ip address and open a connection to it.

You should override the p`channelRegistered`](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.html#channelRegistered-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext-), and check if the channel is already active using an if statement on `ctx.channel().isActive()`, and if its active, directly start sending your message.

Notice that for most protocols, it's better to let the client send something first, as in that case, an attacker cannot quickly gets your application name and version from a random port, and allows port unification, where you run multiple services on the same port.